# Why is my csproj File Changing When I Publish a Solution?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Team Foundation Server and Git.

Whenever I publish my project with `alt` + `b` + `h` I am told that there has been one change in the repo:

[image]

When I investigate, I can see that the file that changed is `MyProject.csproj`.

However, upon viewing the changes, I can see that there is literally no difference between the old and new files:

[image]

However there does appear to be 2 warnings on this line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Where `MSBuildToolsVersion` is highlighted but there is no message.

I would like to `.gitignore` the `.csproj`file, but I have read that this should not be done as it may actually change in future. Is this true, and is what I am experiencing normal or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Are you sure the version number is not being incremented? That is default behavior when you publish, and the version number is stored in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

number of factors can be:

1) you might have changed the published location path

2) you might just build your solution to new or different version than before

3) you might have published and due to not checked those changes to TFS it is showing you that you have pending check out

you can always do one thing:
go to solution>>source control>>undo pending changes

after you do this , get latest from TFS and build it

Now see if there is any changes if yes you can always compare what are the changes you made.

Comment: This is the correct answer (option 2). Even though visual studio does not actually show me which area in the `.csproj` is updated, I can see that it is on this line: `<ApplicationRevision>47</ApplicationRevision>`